# Two decimal places lost with subtraction

Tags: c#, math

I am trying to subtract two numbers and get a result of decimal number with two decimal places, but when the subtraction is happening, I am getting full number, without any decimals. 
Here is what I am trying:

```
int totalMiles = 1001;
decimal total_used = 0.0M, total_gallons_used = 0.0M;
total_gallons_used = (totalMiles / 46);
```

If the calculation is done correctly, I need to receive result of 21,76 but I am getting only 21 for total_gallons_used.

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's because you are performing an integer [division](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3b1ff23f.aspx) (the two operands are integers). You probably want to perform a real numbers division (one or two of the operands are real numbers):

```
total_gallons_used = (totalMiles / 46M);
```

Now the result will be a real number.